# how to merge json arry in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

merge data according to month wise same month revenu added in own month and month name no replicated

```
[{"revenu":0,"month":"January"},
{"revenu":0,"month":"February"},
{"revenu":0,"month":"March"},
{"revenu":0,"month":"April"},
{"revenu":1832.4430203602753,"month":"May"},
{"revenu":4502.1,"month":"May"},
{"revenu":54.673303657726436,"month":"May"},
{"revenu":0,"month":"June"},
{"revenu":0,"month":"July"},
{"revenu":0,"month":"August"},
{"revenu":0,"month":"September"},
{"revenu":0,"month":"October"},
{"revenu":0,"month":"November"},
{"revenu":0,"month":"December"}]
```

Comment: The question is not clear. If my understanding is right then you want to add up the revenues of each month. For May it will be {"revenue": 6389.21632402, "month": "may"}. Is that correct/

Comment: Get started with `h.group_by { |e| e[:month] }`

Answer (score 2):

```
new_arr = given_array.group_by{ |data| data[:month]}
new_arr.map{|key, val| {"month": key, "revenu": val.inject(0){|sum, hash| sum + hash[:revenu]}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sample = []
    array.each do |data|
        sample_hash = {}
        check_exi = sample.select {|h| h[:month] == data[:month]}
        if check_exi.empty?
            sample_hash[:revenu] = data[:revenu]
            sample_hash[:month] = data[:month]
            sample.push(sample_hash)
        else
            check_exi[0][:revenu] = check_exi[0][:revenu] + data[:revenu]
        end
    end
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 2):

```
grouped = array.group_by { |d| d[:month] }
new_array = []
grouped.each do |data|
  list = {}
  sum = 0
  month = ""
  data[1].each do |e|
    sum = sum + e[:revenu]
    month = e[:month]
  end
  list[:revenu] = sum
  list[:month] = month
  new_array.push(list)
end
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make use of [**`group_by`**](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by) to group the data by `:month` and then use [**`sum`**](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum) to add the revenue.

```
array
  .group_by{ |data| data[:month] }
  .map{ |k, v| {month: k, revenu: v.sum { |m| m[:revenu] || 0}} }

#=> [{:month=>"January", :revenu=>0},
#=> {:month=>"February", :revenu=>0},
#=> {:month=>"March", :revenu=>0},
#=> {:month=>"April", :revenu=>0},
#=> {:month=>"May", :revenu=>6389.216324018002},
#=> {:month=>"June", :revenu=>0},
#=> {:month=>"July", :revenu=>0},
#=> {:month=>"August", :revenu=>0},
#=> {:month=>"September", :revenu=>0},
#=> {:month=>"October", :revenu=>0},
#=> {:month=>"November", :revenu=>0},
#=> {:month=>"December", :revenu=>0}]
```